# My android emulator can't run my card view project successfully

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please, anytime I create a project with `CardViews`, my android emulator can't successfully run the app. Please help me, it's been happening for 2 days now. I followed this tutorial to learn how to use card views, which returned no errors but my emulator can't run the app successfully https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: post cardview code and activity code

Comment: it's quite long. I followed the exact thing the tutorial in the link said

Comment: I tried pasting all my codes in the question but I can't format very well so it refused to upload

Comment: can you show the logcat error?

Comment: it doesn't display any errors, just shows app closed on the emulator